# How can I enable/disable my JTextField depending of the state of a JCheckBox?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jcheckbox

I have a Java check box next to a text field.

When the check box gets selected, I want the text box to be enabled and when it isn't, I don't want it to be selected.  I tried an `if` statement with the `isSelected()` method, but it didn't do anything.

How can I react to state changes of the JCheckBox?

Comment: "Talk is cheap. Show me the code." [Linus Torvalds]

Answer (score 15):

Suggestion:

1. Read the [How to Use Check Boxes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#checkbox) tutorial
2. Register an [`ItemListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html) for the `JCheckBox` instance
3. Compare state change (i.e. [`getStateChange()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html#getStateChange%28%29)) to either [`ItemEvent.SELECTED`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html#SELECTED), or [`ItemEvent.DESELECTED`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html#DESELECTED), and then appropriately invoke `foo.setEnabled`, where `foo` is the `JTextBox` instance.

---

Here's an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org):

```
public final class JCheckBoxDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();             
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("JCheckBox Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(JCheckAndTextPane.newInstance());
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(250, 75)); // for demonstration purposes only
        //frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static final class JCheckAndTextPane extends JPanel{
        private JCheckAndTextPane(){
            super();

            // Create components
            final JTextField textField = new JTextField("Enabled");
            final JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("Enable", true);
            checkBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
                @Override
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                    if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                        textField.setEnabled(true);
                        textField.setText("Enabled");
                    }
                    else if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED){
                        textField.setEnabled(false);
                        textField.setText("Disabled");
                    }

                    validate();
                    repaint();
                }
            });

            add(checkBox);
            add(textField);
        }

        public static final JCheckAndTextPane newInstance(){
            return new JCheckAndTextPane();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: 2 notes.  1) An SSCCE should include the imports (not all of us run automagic IDEs that will figure them out!).  2) For tips on making great screen shots (especially getting rid of the 'stray pixels' in the rounded corners), see the [How do I create screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) FAQ.  Those 2 points aside, +1.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`isSelected`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#isSelected%28%29) method.

You then use an [`ItemListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html) so you'll be notified when it's checked or unchecked.

And depending on the state of the isSelected method, then you can enable or disable the `JTextBox`.

Answer (score 0):

// >Click checkbox > Add Event handler > Item > ItemStateChange > Type the code

// chckBox1 is my Variable name

```
    chckBox2.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

            if(chckBox2.isSelected()) {
                txtAddCandles.setEnabled(true);
            }

        }
    });
```